# Does Parse.com JS work as a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, google-chrome-extension, parse-platform

I'm new to both Parse and Chrome Extension development so this might be a pretty basic question:

I'm trying to develop a chrome extension which reads and writes data to Parse.com. The current app I have is quite simple, and while it works perfectly in Chrome (as a browser), it does not work as Chrome Extension. Any ideas of something I might be overlooking?

**The nuts and bolts:**

I have an index.html that points to jquery.min.js, parse-1.2.18.min.js, myownscript.js

myownscript.js looks like this:

```
$(function() {

    Parse.$ = jQuery;

    Parse.initialize("OMITTED",
                   "OMITTED");


    var Users = Parse.Object.extend("Users");
    var users = new Users();


    $("button").click(function(){
        users.save({name: $("#name").val()}, {
            success: function(object) {
                $(".success").show();
            },
            error: function(model, error) {
                $(".error").show();
            }
        });
        users.save({email: $("#email").val()}); 
    });   
});
```

Comment: I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work as a chrome extension. Perhaps it has to do with packaging of the extension?

Comment: Looks like I got a Chrome App and a Chrome Extension confused. It runs as an extension (say a pop-up) but it won't run as an app. I've added "https://api.parse.com/" to permissions but still no luck.

Comment: What errors are you getting in the console? [How to debug](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging).

Comment: @abraham, thanks for the tip. This is the error message I'm getting from parse-1.2.18.min.js: "window.localStorage is not available in packaged apps.Use chrome.storage.local instead." Looks like fixing this in Parse will be tough...

Comment: Not sure if window.sessionStorage is available in packaged apps either but `window.localStorage = window.sessionStorage;` before you add Parse might work.

Comment: Did you move forward on this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to paste this code before parse initialization:

```
function ChromeStorageController(){
    var store = {};//Object.create(null);
    store.async = 1;
    store.getItemAsync = function(path){
        var get = new Parse.Promise()
        chrome.storage.local.get(path,function(data){
                //careful here: get return a key,value pair but we only need the value
                get.resolve(data[path]);
        });
        return get;
    };
    store.setItemAsync = function(path,value){
        var set = new Parse.Promise()
        var item = Object.create(null);
        item[path] = value;
        chrome.storage.local.set(item, function(err){
            if(err){
                set.reject(err);
            }else{
                set.resolve(value);
            }
        });
        return set;
    };
    store.removeItemAsync = function(path){
        var remove = new Parse.Promise()
        chrome.storage.local.remove(path,function(err){
            if(err){
                remove.reject(err);
            }else{
                remove.resolve();
            }
        })
        return remove;
    };
    store.clear = function(){
        chrome.storage.local.clear();
    };
    return store;
}
Parse.CoreManager.setStorageController(ChromeStorageController())
```

The solution is posted here:
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-JS/issues/72

thanks to quorak